# How to set the distance between content and footer using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The code below works very well(controls the distance and makes the footer it stick) however I need to edit the distance between footer and content as there is a very big gap! I am using the software visual studio 2014, java script in asp.net.

Masterpage.Master HTML % JavaScript code:

```
 <body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            var footer = $("#footer");
            var pos = footer.position();
            var height = $(window).height();
            height = height - pos.top;
            height = height - footer.height();
            if (height > 0) {
                footer.css({
                    'margin-top': height + 'px'
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#footer {

    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(foot_bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;

}
```

I have tried to adjust it but getting no where fast! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: providing the relevant html/css would be extremely helpful.

Comment: thank you I have now added css & html.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around what you are trying to accomplish and failing. If you want to eliminate the space between your content and your footer then simply add `margin-top: 0;` to your `#footer` css class.

Comment: @ Chris Pickford I tried change css and nothing happens because it is the javascript setting the distance.

Comment: @user3515765 it might also be helpful to describe what you are trying to accomplish, rather than what you've done and how what you've done isn't working... seems like there's still some confusion about the expected end result (myself included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit confusing since you are stating that you want it to stick (at the bottom) but you want to reduce the gap between the footer and the content.

One of these ways is possible at a time considering that the footer has a fixed height.

If you want to reduce the gap between the footer and the content, then remove the footer from your main div and add a margin-top to the amount you wish inside your #footer.

```
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

If you want a sticky footer which stays below the content, you can check out the tutorial on the link below:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

This will scroll with the content if it extends.

A third option would be to user position:fixed and bottom:0px for your footer so it stays at the bottom of the page and the content scrolls behind it.

N.B: In all these cases, you will not need your JS code.